# Why does Blackbeard need a crew if he has his magical sword?

Tags: pirates-of-the-caribbean, on-stranger-tides

He has the Sword of Triton that can control the ship, right?  That's how he tied up his crew and stuff.  So why does he need them anyway if he can control the ship with his sword alone?

Comment: To get stuff done OUTSIDE the ship?

Comment: Can the sword cook food or clean the captain's clothes? (or the ship itself, but i don't think the pirates really cared about the _ship_ being clean)

Comment: To admire his luxuriant beard?

Comment: Because otherwise, he'd have to use the sword to do everything himself.  Better to use it to terrify people into doing those things for him.  What's the use of magical powers if they only give you more work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Common reasons he would need a crew:

[I take from the wikia.](http://pirates.wikia.com/wiki/Sword_of_Triton) For point one.

> Anyone brandishing the sword would rule the ship, controlling the
>   vessel to do his indomitable will. Despite its great power, the
>   sword's power was diminished away from any ship.

So technically he needed someone to help **outside** the ship, and possibly if the ship was overrun. So if you take that to be canon, then there is a answer.

**Companionship:**

He could possibly keep people around so that he is not alone. So that he has some level of companionship.

**He has a wider scope with a crew**

He has his sword, but the sword isn't omnipotent. He can get more things done by using a crew and if his sword fails(unlikely) he has his crew. But if his crew fails, he has his sword. Plus, he can probably get more things done, with both the crews and the sword's combined efforts.

**Just because:**

He could possibly keep a crew, because that is what captains do. He might do it to keep up appearances and because he is a captain. So he needs people to command.

*This is a very weak option though, so I put more stock in the other ones.*

---

***I don't think it was ever addressed(why he would need a crew?) in the canon. Though, I may be wrong.***

Answer (score 4):

Well, he probably wants to do things other than constantly concentrating on getting the ship to sail itself.  Like eating, sleeping, pissing, doing anything else.

Also the sword is only useful on board a ship, so unless he plans on tracking the fountain on his own he will need a crew.  He probably didn't want to carry the mermaid all the way inland himself.

Comment: I'm flip-flopping between wanting to upvote and wanting to downvote simply for the unncessary use of the word "pissing" XD

Comment: Yeah, but this is Blackbeard we are talking about.  Thought it would be appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Well use of the sword requires him being always at a position to use. So if he falls asleep, passes out, gets sick or everything else that could render him temporarily incapable of using the sword then the ship would follow a random course. While keeping a crew you can run a ship even while you are asleep

Answer (score 0):

To use them as soldiers/warriors I suppose, also to clean and maintain the ship

Comment: "I suppose" is not really what people usually seek. They look for canon evidence

Comment: This seems to be more of a comment than a stand alone answer, if it was fleshed out with some canon evidence then maybe it would be an answer